# How to generate a "canned response" with several variables

Tags: ruby

I'm brand new to Ruby and programming. I'd like to create a little program to automate one of my more tedious work tasks that I'm currently doing by hand but I'm not sure where to start.

People register to take courses through an online form, and I receive their registration information at the end of each day as a CSV document. I go line by line through that document and generate a confirmation email to send to them based on their input on the online form: the course they'd like to take, their room preference, how much they chose to pay for the course (sliding scale), etc. The email ends up looking something like this:

Dear So and so, Thank you for signing up for "Such-and-such An Awesome Course," with Professor Superdude. The course starts on Monday, September 1, 2030 at 4pm and ends on Thursday at 1pm. You paid such-and-such an amount...

et cetera. So ideally the program would take in the CSV document with information like "student name," "course title," "fee paid," and generate emails based on blocks of text ("Dear ***, Thank you for signing up for _***,") and variables (the dates of the course) that are stored externally so they are easy to edit without going into the source code (maybe as CSV and plain text files).

Additionally, I need the output to be in rich text, so I can bold and underline certain things. I'm familiar with Markdown so I could use that in the source code but it would be ideal if the output could be rich text.

I'm not expecting anyone to write a program for me, but if you could let me know what I should look into or even what I should Google, that would be very helpful.

Comment: You should probably start with reading some books. [Programming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0), for example.

Comment: Ruby is great and all, but isn't this task exactly what MS Word's Mail Merge is for? There's probably an equivalent in Open Office also.

Comment: @tigeravatar I wouldn't wish Word's mail merge on anyone.

Comment: @tadman It can be difficult to wrap your head around at first.  Regardless, and personal opinions aside, it can do exactly what is needed based on the question's description

Comment: @tigeravatar It's not that it's difficult, it's that it's a desktop application which costs a significant amount of money, requires a lot of investment in getting the template to work, and no matter what you do, at the end of the day all you have is a Word document which 99% of the time is completely useless by itself. The question is for a **Ruby** answer, not Word.

Comment: I could swear I didn't see the word "email" when I first saw this question, but I think I would only use Word mail merge to send email if I had less than a few dozen messages to send. After a hundred messages or so, I'd be much happier with a ruby solution that sends email directly, and it's not that much more work to code than it is to use mail merge.

Comment: @tadman I get that.  I looked it up and OpenOffice (which is free) does support mail merge, so that takes care of the cost.  As for usability, It's a lot of work to create an understand something like this in a programming language that the asker has admitted to being "brand new to".  Mail Merge provides a solution without having to reinvent the wheel so to speak.  That all being said, it was simply a suggestion for an alternate solution.

Comment: @tigeravatar Mail merge died in the 1990s. Please don't bring it back. That and balloon pants. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to put together an email. If so, I'd probably start with a simple ERB template. If you want to generate HTML, you can write one HTML template and one plain text template; variable substitution works the same way for both, with the exception that you'll need to html-escape anything that contains characters that HTML considers special (ampersands, greater than, less then, for example). See [ERB Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) here.

If you're trying to parse CSV, user FasterCSV or a similar library. [FasterCSV is documented](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) here.

If you want to send an email, you can use [ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html), the mail gem, or the [pony](https://github.com/benprew/pony) gem. ActionMailer is part of rails, but can be used independently. Pony is a good facade for creating email, as well; both ActionMailer and Pony depend on the "mail" gem, so unless you want to spend more time thinking about how email formats work, use one of those.

If you're not trying to send an email, and instead are trying to create a formatted document, you can still use ERB, but use it to generate output in TeX, or if you're more adventurous than I am, a Word compatible XML document. Alternatively, if you're wedded to Microsoft Word or RTF, you might try either http://ruby-rtf.rubyforge.org/ (Ruby RTF) or use COM/OLE interop to talk to Word, but I would only do that if really I had to; if I had to go that route, I'd probably suck it up and just use the built in mail merge feature in Word perhaps with a little VBA code.

Comment: Also worth exploring as a template option: [Moustache](http://mustache.github.io/). The `{{name}}` placeholder is a lot easier for non-technical people to work with than `<%=name%>` like in ERB.

Comment: There are a bunch of options, including Haml, which I use for some projects, and Slim, which I use for others, especially those with semantic HTML, but I never can seem to fully escape using ERB in most projects, since ERB is always there, and convenient for things that aren't like HTML. Moustache is a good choice if your model perfectly corresponds to what you want to render, though it puts a slightly greater burden on the developer to get all those things right.

Comment: the FasterCSV & TeX advice is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!
@tadman I'll check out Moustache!

Comment: I've been using ruby for some time now, so I sometimes fail to note important details on things I've also used for a while, such as: FasterCSV is now actually the default CSV parser in Ruby 1.9, so it's not necessary to pull it in as a gem, you can just use the ruby 1.9 CSV library.